# Group results by multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement facebook-like messaging system in my Rails app.

My **message** model looks like this:

```
sender_id:references
receiver_id:references
body:text
is_read:bolean
```

Now i need to display all messages between current logged in user and other users so i'm using this code:

```
Message.where("sender_id = '#{current_user.id}' OR receiver_id = '#{current_user.id}'")
```

However, this query threats `send` messages and `received` messages separately. I need to somehow group them by both `receiver_id` and `sender_id` columns to display a list of users, with whom currently logged-in user has ever exchanged a messages with (just like on facebook) but i'm not quite sure how it should be properly done.

Any help would be appreciated. If you think it should be done a different way, feel free to tell me that :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first. Never directly interpolate (using `#{}`) in a `.where()` call if you can avoid it (you pretty much always can). In this particular case, it's probably not doing any huge harm, but if you get into a habit of doing it, you'll eventually open yourself up to a SQL injection attack. Use one of the techniques Rails provides that interpolates and sanitizes. Here's one:

```
messages = Message.where("sender_id = :user_id OR receiver_id = :user_id", :user_id => current_user.id)
```

Now, as to the question itself. Assuming you're not trying to paginate these results or anything along those lines, you're going to be loading all the Message objects into memory anyway, so you don't lose anything by grouping them in Ruby instead of in SQL:

```
 grouped_messages = messages.group_by do |m|
    if m.sender_id == current_user.id
      m.receiver_id
    else
      m.sender_id
    end
 end
```

Essentially, this groups the messages by the id of whichever of the sender or receiver isn't the current user. `grouped_messages` will be a Hash, the keys of which are the other user's id, and the values are arrays of Message objects.